# How to use Nvidia as default GPU/ Disable intel gpu

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, bios, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a computer running an i7 4771, Gigabyte z87M-D3H and Nvidia gtx760. For some reason when I am using an HDMI cable the gpu will not render my desktop and instead the default Intel gpu is used. When I run msinfo32 and check under display it confirms this. In devmgmt.msc I can see that both the Nvidia card and the Intel HD gpu are detected.

So the question is: Is there any way for me to disable the Intel GPU so that the computer is forced to use the Nvidia card? Is it safe to do this or is it safe to simply right click and disable the Intel gpu in devmgmt.msc? I have done a lot of research and have found that by default the Intel GPU is by default enabled in the BIOS. Would the best way be to disable it through the bios?

Any feedback would be appreciated. If there are any completely safe ways to do this or an alternative that I have not found I would be really grateful.

Comment: The simplest solution is don't install the Intel drivers but if your plugging in the monitor to the Intel GPU it will do this you don't need to disable the Intel GPU just don't install the drivers

Comment: @Ramhound should I uninstall them and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BIOS there's usually a setting for which video adapter to prefer, although yours might have a preferred output (HDMI vs DVI) as well.  That's highly dependent on your motherboard model and BIOS version - it's almost always best practice to upgrade to the latest BIOS version.

Comment: There is possibly an update for the bios but I always  use that as a last resort because from my experience bios updates are pretty risky..

Comment: There not risky; but at the same time you have a problem so you need to try all possible solutions